# bot.get_user(id) стал возвращать "None". Раньше все работало

Tags: python, discord

Буквально 2 недели назад, данный ниже код работал. То есть, я пишу в чат `"!status id_пользователя"`, а затем, бот возвращает в консоль его ник и тег в формате `"имя_пользователя#0000"`.

Сейчас, при запуске этого же кода, какой id я не укажу, бот всегда возвращает `None` в консоль. При этом не поменялось ничего вообще, пользователи не меняли ник (хоть от этого и не зависит id) и уж тем более не удаляли свой аккаунт. В чем может быть проблема?

```
@bot.command()
async def status(ctx, arg):
    user = bot.get_user(int(arg))
    print(user)
```

Comment: А `id` пользователя там точно `int`, а не строка?

Comment: Да, точно, [документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user)

Comment: Вообщем, проблема точно не в моем коде: [тык](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2195)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, более-менее разобравшись в проблеме готов помочь тем, кто столкнулся или еще столкнется с подобной проблемой в дискорде. А таких будет много :)

**Причина по которой произошел сбой в работе моего кода:**

> Шлюз был обновлен несколько дней назад и теперь вам нужно добавлять намерения для работы бота

Грубо говоря, вышло обновление, немного изменившее принцип работы дискорд-бота.

**Как устранить проблему:**

Поняв, что проблема определенно не в коде, обратился в поддержку дискорда: [моя заявка](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2195). Там мне сообщили, что для восстановления работы бота я должен выдать ему необходимые намерения. Какие конкретно нужны, я еще не разобрался, поэтому пока что выдал вообще все. Делается это так:

Обновляем библиотеку: `pip install --upgrade discord.py`

```
# объявляем намерения. all() означает, что выдаем все
intents = discord.Intents.all()

# при определении бота и его префикса, определяем также намерения
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

**Дополнительно:**

Подробнее об это можно почитать [здесь](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994). Данную ссылку мне дали в поддержке. Всем удачи, надеюсь не придется искать решение проблемы также долго как мне :)

---

*Также можно оформить данный код так, чтобы он работал без выдачи намерений. Вместо `get_user()` использовать `await fetch_user()`.*

```
@bot.command()
async def status(ctx, arg):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(int(arg))
    print(user)
```

Comment: советую принять свой ответ

Comment: >Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 23 часа

Comment: понятно. придётся ждать